# Is it possible to alias a command prefix for redirecting stdout?

Tags: command-line, bash

Sorry about the non-informative heading...

What I'm looking for is something like that will allow me to shorten redirecting stdout.
I know that executing a command with whitespaces before it does not write it into history, and there are a few "magic" operators, such as "!!", etc.

I'm basically looking for something like that, that would allow me to replace `>/dev/null`, so, I'll be able to write, for example

`git pull !!!` and that would be equivalent to `git pull>/dev/null`

Is there something like this? Am I able to override an existing operator / write a new one?

Comment: Maybe what you want is option `-q` for `git pull`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alias expansion only looks at the first token / word of a line, so there's no way for `git pull !!!` to get replaced by alias expansion.

However, redirects work even if placed before the command, so you can do it with an alias:

```
alias quiet='>/dev/null '
```

Leaving whitespace at the end of the alias expansion makes bash consider the next token for alias expansion.  (This is why it's common to do `alias sudo='sudo '`).  So this won't even break your aliases.  Example:

```
$ ll *.s xyz
ls: cannot access 'xyz': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 12 Mar  6 20:15 a64.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 72 Mar  6 21:03 arm.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 30 Mar 15 17:38 foo.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter 42 Mar  6 13:12 mips.s
$ quiet ll *.s xyz     # ll alias expanded successfully, stdout discarded
ls: cannot access 'xyz': No such file or directory
$                      # stderr is not redirected.
```

Comment: Minor caveat: redirections work before *simple* commands. You can't do something like `> /dev/null for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done`.

Answer (score 16):

I'd use a function

```sh
quietly() {
    # execute the remaining arguments as a command, but redirect output
    "$@" > /dev/null
}

quietly git pull
```

Or a function that reads stdin and discards it:

```sh
q() { cat > /dev/null; }

git pull | q
```

Neither of these redirect stderr: if something goes wrong, you should know about it.

Comment: You can simply use an alias, as per my answer.  Seems simpler, although neither way has any major advantage over the other that I can think of.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alias expansion works rather differently from the rest of shell parsing (including that of functions) and can be a lot more confusing when you get into its edge cases. This is why the [ALIASES section of the manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ALIASES) says, "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Comment: Functions are massively more flexible than simple aliases. I almost never use an alias any more except for trivial things.

Answer (score 5):

Aliasing is possible as indicated by the answer of [Peter Cordes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397782/558158). Another approach is setting up an environment variable. This allows for a more natural redirection syntax:

```
export d0='/dev/null'
```

which you then can use as

```
git pull >$d0
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, yes, but **not** through aliases – instead by using bash's `extdebug` function, which allows making arbitrary changes to a command before it is executed (by suppressing the original command and eval'ing the new one).

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap "code goes here" DEBUG
```

The trap handler will get the original input in `$BASH_COMMAND`, and returning 1 from the handler will cancel original the command. If you enter multiple `;`-separated commands, the trap is invoked separately for each one.

Specifically:

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap 'if [[ $BASH_COMMAND == *!!!* ]]; then
          eval "${BASH_COMMAND//!!!/"> /dev/null"}"; false
      fi' DEBUG
```

This will replace any `!!!` with `> /dev/null` anywhere inside the command. You won't be able to do `echo 'Hi!!!'` anymore.

If you prefer to match only at the end of command, that's easy too.

```
trap 'if [[ $BASH_COMMAND == *\ quietly ]]; then
          eval "${BASH_COMMAND% quietly} > /dev/null"; false
      fi' DEBUG
```

As another example, you can use this to alias `command please` to `sudo command`:

```
trap 'case $BASH_COMMAND in *\ please) eval sudo ${BASH_COMMAND% *}; false; esac' DEBUG
```

---

There is another way to achieve a similar thing: you can redefine keys in Bash (readline) using either `bind` or `~/.inputrc`, which you can also use to redefine key *sequences*.

For example, inputrc entry `"!!!": "> /dev/null"` or the equivalent shell command `bind '"!!!": "> /dev/null"'` will cause the text `> /dev/null` to be inserted whenever you attempt to type `!!!`.

Note that Bash cannot predict future, which means that if you only want to type a *single* `!`, there will be a slight delay before it appears – that's Bash waiting to see whether it'll match the sequence. This can get annoying, so don't bind letters and stuff.

In fact, it would be a better idea to bind a Ctrl or Alt hotkey instead. For example, you could create a <kbd>Alt+Q</kbd> hotkey using `"\eq": "> /dev/null"`.

Previously: https://superuser.com/a/1459211